# On scrolling UIview height changing using ScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue in `UIScrollView`. I have an a `UIScrollView`, `UIView` and `UIButton`. On button click height of UIView is changing, but when I scrolled the `UIScrollView` then `UIView` height get the previous height back.

```
-(IBAction)press:(id)sender

{
    self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(60, 60, 180, 160);
    self.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question :( could you explain it better?

Comment: i am using scrollview and on scrollview using uiview and on button click uiview height changing, but when i scroll the page uiview height changed its initial height

Comment: That's not a built-in behavior. There must be some code you wrote doing that. Have you debugged your code?

Comment: It would help if you could provide more information or show more of your code :)

Comment: yes i debbuged, view height changed to my new xy position, but when i scroll the page its view height back to initial xy position

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.myScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,900)];
    self.myScroll.delegate = self;
}

-(IBAction)press:(id)sender
{
    self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(60, 60, 180, 160);
    self.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

Comment: What is the effect you want to achieve? do you want to change the size of the UIScrollView or the UIView? Are those the only methods inside the viewController?

Comment: i want to change the size of uiview

Comment: on button action i am changing the size of uiview

Comment: This code should work. In the code you posted in the above comments, you set the delegate of the scrollView. check if you are not setting/configuring the myView.frame on the scrollView delegate.

Comment: yes i am setting delegate

Comment: Can you post what delegate calls you implemented from the UIScrollViewDelegate? and what is written in them?